# HBase Read using Spark-HBase Hortonworks connector takes a long time

Tags: apache-spark, hbase, apache-spark-sql

Have used the HortonWorks Spark HBase Connector to read and write my HBase Table.

During the Read Process, as per the below snippet, the read timetaken is 4 Minutes for 2.3 Million Records.
I am using RowKey as a primary column to Filter Records.

Total Records count is around 3.5 Million.

We are using a 3 Node Cluster | 3 Region Servers | 11 Regions for 3 Region Servers.

```
val catalog = getUDMHistoryTableCatalog()
val HistoryHBaseDF = sqlContext.read
  .options(Map(HBaseTableCatalog.tableCatalog -> catalog))
  .format("org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase")
  .load().filter(substring(col("key"),0,4) === "017-")
```

Comment: Is your data distributed evenly in you region servers? Make sure you are not dealing with 'hotspotting' in HBase. Check this out: http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#rowkey.design

Comment: The Rowkey that I am using is as per the below format


ABCDE2017-02-28 09:30:00
.....
.....
ZXYZ2017-02-28 23:30:00


Due to this format, I believe there should not be any hotspotting.